# jQuery multicolumn checklist - sorting vertically

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, sorting

Using jQuery [toChecklist](http://www.scotthorlbeck.com/code/tochecklist/) plugin, I set the checklist to be multicolumn, but even though my original `select` options are sorted, they are not anymore within the multicolumn checklist (they are, but horizontally, and not vertically, so it has a less natural feeling when seeking through it).

I'm trying to order the items vertically but it seems like I cannot find the proper way to fix it.

```
$('#dsi_infos_departements_select').toChecklist({
    showCheckboxes : false,
    addSearchBox : false,
    addScrollBar : false,
    listWidth : 628, 
    itemWidth : 150 
});
```

[image: It's ordered from right to left, it's good but it should prioritize top to bottom first!]

Here is an overview of the final html:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aCgZu/)